# SQL queries in RDD

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I must operate with RDD by Scala/Spark methods and by SQL queries.

Is it possible to operate with RDD **directly** via SQL queries?

The proposed ways (schemaRDD or DataFrame) require extra memory leakage.

After such a transformation I have in the memory two identical huge objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in a way, you may be able to do so. But you'll need to create your own version of DataFrame.

DataFrame is an abstraction over RDDs. Nevertheless, joins, filters, etc. the features that you find with Spark-SQL are optimized with DataFrames but they were made on RDDs first.

Comment: I have seen that DataFrame is restricted by 22 fields, may be it is not true.

Comment: That's not true. Case classes in Scala are restricted by 22 fields. That's something else.

Comment: Instead of using read API to load a file into DataFrame and query it, you can also query that file directly with SQL.  What kind of file is mentioned?  Is it possible to use persistence that was created via saveAsObjectFile ???

Comment: What do you mean by your last comment ?

Comment: Sorry. Don't mentioned. The last comment is incorrect.  Only parquet files can be used for direct SQL queries.